# What is promotional codes in ios sdk ? why we use them?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

can any one please tell me what is promotional codes ? why we uses promotional codes? any tutorial for the same. Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promotional codes can be sent to users to download an app for free via iTunes. A registered developer can create a promo code to send to someone via iTunes Connect.

Check out this tutorial for more details... http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_generate_promo_promotional_code_iphone_app.html